# C++ Compiler error with calls

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

In my Computer Science class we are making a program that asks for the height, bottom, and top measurements of 4 isosceles trapezoids, calculates the perimeter and determines which has the largest perimeter.  My program isn't complete yet, but I am getting errors saying that there is no matching function to call for `askInput`, `calcPerimeter`, and `findMax`.  Here is the code for context (Sorry if the answer is obvious, or my code is sloppy, this is the first programming class I have taken).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void intro();
void askInput();
double calcPerimeter();
double findMax();
double highest;

int main()
{
    intro();

    double t1, b1, h1, p1;  //Top, bottom, height, and perimiter of first trapezoid
    double t2, b2, h2, p2,
           t3, b3, h3, p3,
           t4, b4, h4, p4;  //other four trapezoids
    double max;             //largest perimeter

    askInput(t1, b1, h1, "first");
    askInput(t2, b2, h2, "second");
    askInput(t3, b3, h3, "third");
    askInput(t4, b4, h4, "fourth");

    p1 = calcPerimeter(t1, b1, h1);
    p2 = calcPerimeter(t2, b2, h2);
    p3 = calcPerimeter(t3, b3, h3);
    p4 = calcPerimeter(t4, b4, h4);

    max = findMax(p1, p2, p3, p4);

    cout << "Results" << endl;
    cout << "\tFirst: \tTop:" << t1 << "\tBottom: " << b1 << "\tHeight: " << h1 << "\tPerimeter: " << p1 << endl;
    cout << "\tSecond: \tTop:" << t2 << "\tBottom: " << b2 << "\tHeight: " << h2 << "\tPerimeter: " << p2 << endl;
    cout << "\tThird: \tTop:" << t3 << "\tBottom: " << b3 << "\tHeight: " << h3 << "\tPerimeter: " << p3 << endl;
    cout << "\tFourth: \tTop:" << t4 << "\tBottom: " << b4 << "\tHeight: " << h4 << "\tPerimeter: " << p4 << endl;
    cout << endl << "\tLargest Perimeter: " << highest << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void intro()
{
    cout << "Lab G: Trapezoid with largest perimeter" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------" << endl; \
    cout << "This program will calculate the perimeter of four trapezoids." << endl;
    cout << "You will have to enter the top, bottom, and height of each trapezoid." << endl;
    cout << "The program will then find the trapezoid with the largest perimeter and output it." << endl;
}

void askInput(double &top, double &bottom, double &height, string whichT)
{
    cout << "Enter values for the " << whichT << " trapezoid." << endl;
    cout << "\tTop: ";
    cin >> top;
    cout << "\tBottom: ";
    cin >> bottom;
    cout << "\tHeight: ";
    cin >> height;
}

double calcPerimeter(double top, double bottom, double height)
{
    double answer;

    //some calculations

    return answer;
}

double findMax(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
    double highest;
    highest = a;
    if (b > highest)
    {
        highest = b;
    }
    if (c > highest)
    {
        highest = c;
    }
    if (d > highest)
    {
        highest = d;
    }
    return highest;
}
```

Comment: If you found an answer useful, accept it. That way you thank the one who helped you most, and you don't have to edit an "answered" into the question. :)

Comment: do not edit the question to thank or say that it's solved. simply accepting the helpful answer is enough

Comment: It wouldn't let me answer at first, and everyone who commented answered my question so I didn't know what to do.  Thank you for the heads up though, I will do that in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration and definition of function do not match . Declare them as you have done in your definition and this should work.

```
 void askInput(); --> 
 void askInput(double &, double &, double &, string );

 double calcPerimeter();-->
 double calcPerimeter(double & , double & , double& );

 double findMax();-->
 double findMax(double &, double &, double &, double &);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function signature in the declaration has to match the signature in the implementation. This means that the declaration has to contain all the needed types of the function parameters.

```
void askInput(double &top, double &bottom, double &height, string whichT);

double calcPerimeter(double top, double bottom, double height);

double findMax(double a, double b, double c, double d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your prototypes for those functions don't include the parameters.  `askInput()` is a different function from `askInput(double &, double&, double&, string)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked on C++, but I think I see at least 2 issues -

1. You need to declare the functions at the top with their full signature.
2. At least for `askInput` you are passing in the values and the de-referencing them. This looks strange to me.

Hope this helps!